# Were Frodo and Sam friends before Gandalf task Sam to look after Frodo?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

By the end of there journey it's obvious that they care about each other and are very close friends, but how close were they before they set off for Rivendell and to destroy the Ring of Power?

Comment: Related, possible dup? [Why Does Samwise Gamgee Call Frodo Baggins 'Mr. Frodo'?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/why-does-samwise-gamgee-call-frodo-baggins-mr-frodo) (questions aren't the same, but I think it answers this one)

Comment: *"how close were they before they set off"*  Close enough to 'lie naked in the dark' together, I suspect.  ;)

Comment: They weren't ever "friends", as I explain in that duplicate question.

Comment: Why did Jesse Pinkman continue to call Walter Mr. White?

Comment: I didn't ask why he called him Mr. Frodo I asked if they were friends before not a duplicate question but I didn't think to look for the answer to my question in that one, but thank you for pointing out the answer could possible be in there.:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sam was a servant of the Baggins' of Bag End (who were land-holders, and therefore wealthier and higher up in the social standing of the Shire). Specifically, he was their gardener.

Sam grew up around the Baggins', as his father (Hamfast Gamgee) was their gardner at the time. I daresay when he was growing up, Hamfast made sure Sam called his Masters 'Mr Baggins' and Master Frodo as well (It would've been Master at the time, as he grew up they would begin to refer to him as 'Mister').

However I believe growing up around the same age, Frodo and Sam were close(r) than you would usually see in a Master/Servant relationship. They still weren't "friends" per se, Sam, with his more serious and sombre nature, still saw the relationship as more professional.

Frodo, who is a lot more extroverted and open, seemed to treat Sam more as a confidant (I remember a part at Bilbo's party where Sam and Frodo discuss Sam's love interest, and Frodo has a laugh with him and jokingly pushes him onto the dance floor with her.

So in conclusion, I would say they were close, but not entirely 'friends'. Frodo most likely 'hung out' with other Hobbits of Gentry (Merry and Pippin perhaps?).

Comment: That dance scene is from the Jackson movies, it doesn't happen in the book. And was it really Frodo to push him, not Merry, Pippin or Fredegar?

Comment: @leftaroundabout - The OP didn't specify which interpretation he wanted. It's been about 10 years since I've read the book (watched the first movie about 2 weeks ago) so I had forgotten whether the scene was in the book or not :P.

Comment: @leftaroundabout There is a reference to a dance at Bilbo's party though. Some of the younger Hobbits assumed Bilbo had finished his speech during a pause, and two are said to have started a dance called the Springle-ring, which Tolkien described as "a pretty dance, but rather vigourous". The big group dance sequence may have been a reference to this.